# azure websites require a login?

Tags: azure

I have used Azure Websites from the beginning and just recently started using git deploy to push .NET solution out.

Everything is good in our dev/test account.

Ops have spun up a different account for our production instances. When we push .NET solutions there it looks like pulling up the solution requires username and password and if I don't provide it I get:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

There is nothing I can see in the Azure configuration that would require credentials and the web.config doesn't require any authentication.  The same web.config works without modifications on dev/test

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "pulling up the solution"? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Please provide more and exact details. i.e. configuration you are using, URL you are accessing, etc. This is very common error when you are missing a default document, because directory browsing is disabled for security reasons!

Comment: configuration I am using - Azure Websites with a .NET solution that is built for .NET 4.5.  I am deploying using git deploy.  The URL I am accessing is. https://dem-gad-01.scm.azurewebsites.net/drivelogin.aspx  On test environment a similar URL pulls up just fine: http://ds-google-test1.azurewebsites.net/drivelogin.aspx ..  Thanks @pranav! Thanks @astaykov!

Comment: All Azure website applications have a scm endpoint, like the one you're trying to hit, which is what you'd use to do git deployment. The credentials for this endpoint is the same as the one you use when you do git push. This [blog post](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2012/06/git-deployment-credentials-adding-more.html) details on how you could reset it if you need to. 
    
That said, if you are trying to reach your actual site, here's the url you need to be using : https://dem-gad-01.azurewebsites.net/drivelogin.aspx

Comment: @Pranav - that's the answer!!! thank you!